# How to generate a function-based index in my Python model migration?

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, indexing, migration

I'm using Django, Python 3.7 and PostGres 9.5.  To speed along a particular query, I want to create this functional index, which I'd normally do in PostGres like so ...

```
CREATE INDEX my_article_idx ON article (regexp_replace(url, '\?.*$', ''))
```

However in the world of Django and auto-generated migrations, I'm not sure how to annotate my class in my models.py file so that this function-based index would be auto-generated.  The field in question in my model looks like this ...

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    url = models.TextField(default='', null=False)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a data migration. Read more about them in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

**Step 1** - create an empty data migration file

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

**Step 2** - Add custom sql to the migration:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.14 on 2018-09-20 08:01
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourapp', '0001_name_of_depending_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql="CREATE INDEX my_article_idx ON article (regexp_replace(url, '\?.*$', ''))",
            reverse_sql='DROP INDEX my_article_idx ON article'
        )
    ]
```

Comment: Hi, I already have a number of migrations generated in my appname/migrations folder, including an appname/migrations/0001_initial.py file.  How would I do what you are suggesting in light of that?

Comment: If you are worried about the line with "dependencies" - Django will correctly choose last migration from migration folder when generating an empty migration. Just run that command from Step 1. Or do you stuck on something else?

Comment: Ah I got confused about what that statement did.  But everything does work as you describe it.  Thx